# Memory leak in Event while broadcasting in Laravel 8.x

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Whenever I try to call an event in Laravel 8, a memory leak happens and it crashes the server.
Here is the event:

```
class NewOrderEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $order_id;
    public $user_id;
    
    public function __construct($order_id, $user_id)
    {
        $this->order_id = $order_id;
        $this->user_id =  $user_id;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        Log::info('Memory usage broadcastOn: '. memory_get_peak_usage());
        return [new Channel('orders-' . $this->user_id)];
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        Log::info('Memory usage broadcastWith: '. memory_get_peak_usage());
        
        return [
            'id' => $this->order_id,
        ];
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return ('orders');
    }
}
```

And the logs:

```
local.INFO: Memory usage broadcastOn: 5787040  
local.INFO: Memory usage broadcastWith: 5787312
```

How can I reduce the memory usage of the event?

I've tried to free `$this->user_id` but it didn't work

> ERROR:
> Request Timeout
> This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact the administrator of this website to increase the 'Connection Timeout'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set up a queue?

Because `ShouldBroadcast` will queue the messages. Try replacing `ShouldBroadcast` with `ShouldBroadcastNow` it will dispatch the message instantly without queuing.

```php
class NewOrderEvent implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
 ...
}
```

**OR** Set up the queue.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues

Comment: I changed it to ```ShouldBroadcastNow``` but it doesn't work

Comment: can you share your `config/broadcasting.php`?

Comment: Yes, the problem was there and I fixed it. thanks, bro <3